# Doctrine: Find manytomany relation where having all items in array

Tags: doctrine

I need help how to find Projects that contains in manytomany relation all items in Array.

For Example have this structure:

```
Project
  - Id - int
  - Name - string
  - Categories - manytomany (Category)

Category
  - Id - int
  - Name - string
```

And I need find Projects, that contains all Categories in array of a IDs for Example (1, 2, 3).

When I use

```
$qbProjects->andWhere($qbProjects->expr()->in('p.categories', [1,2,3]));
```

it found all projects, that have Category with id 1, or 2 or 3, but not all of them.

Comment: Can you just add multiple `andWhere()` lines in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: But what inside `andWhere()` when I use `expr()->eq('c.id', $value)` for each value, where `c` is join `p.categories` I will get zero results

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$categories` is a variable that contains an array of categories that you want to check against `projects`, then you can use a `foreach` loop to created multiple `andWhere()` statements to satisfy all conditions:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $qbProjects->andWhere($qbProjects->expr()->in($category->getId(), 'p.categories'));
}
```

Of course you can modify to your needs if you are getting the Category ids by some other method.

Comment: Result query is: `SELECT p FROM Application\Entity\Project p WHERE 1 IN(p.categories) AND 2 IN(p.categories)`

and get error: `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 95: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'IN'`

Comment: I'm getting the same error message even with your simpler query. Sorry, I'm out of ideas!